# Is it safe to reuse unrefrigerated canola oil for deep frying?

Tags: chicken, frying, oil, deep-frying

Last night I deep fried some frozen chicken wings. After letting the oil cool, I filtered it through a cheese cloth and put it in a bottle. But I didn't refrigerate it. How long will it keep like this? Does it have to be refrigerated or frozen to be safe?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The other question doesn't address refrigeration or chicken specifically, nor does it address the safety question.

Comment: @BenPiper It seems like a duplicate to me. The other question is general, so it should apply to everything, including chicken, and it simply asks how to do it. The answers don't say they apply only to specific foods, and don't mention a need to refrigerate, so it seems like they'd apply to your question as well. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: All right, marked as duplicate for now, but if there is actually something new you're trying to ask, just say (or better yet, edit your question), flag the question, and I can reopen it for you immediately!